# How to debug AJAX request errors

Tags: 7, ajax, chaos-tool-suite

PHP errors will be debugged from "Error Logs".

I am working on ctools ajax popup forms. And I always get ajax error.

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 500
Debugging information follows.
Path: /system/ajax
StatusText: Internal Server Error
ResponseText:
```

Is there any possiblity to debug AJAX errors just like PHP error logs?

Comment: Did you set the ini mentioned in [Show all errors while developing](https://www.drupal.org/node/1056468)? If yes, the responseText should contains that information.

Comment: @JimmyKo, Yes indeed..

Comment: Try to open your ajax url in a new tab.

Comment: @ARUN, when i used newtab it is working fine, but when in ctools popup I am facing this issue.